# Building an Average Load Time per Visit Metric in AA

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to build a per-visit average page load time metric in Adobe Analytics for use in analysis such as average page load time versus conversion rate (Example: Users with avg load time between 0-1s convert at X rate, users between 1-2s convert at Y rate, users between 2-3s convert at Z rate, etc).

We currently have page load time implemented as an event and an eVar on all pages, being captured in ms (ex: On loading the home page, we'll see eVar10=1782 and event10=1782). The eVar is set as a text string set to expire on hit with most recent allocation, while the event is set as an "up is bad" always record numeric with participation enabled.

My first instinct was simply a calculated metric with the Event divided by Page Views, but that ends up aggregating at too high a level (the grand total of all load speeds is divided by the grand total of page views). I tried throwing in various summation functions, but it all ended up equally garbage.

Is it possible to build Average-Per-Visit metrics in AA? Is my implementation even going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this? This might not be exactly what you want, but the calculated metric might help.  If you divide your page load time metric by "page load time instances" you can get an average.  Which if you have an evar for session id or username, etc, you can find the average load time per session or user.  In the example below I use Day as the dimension, but you could use whatever evar you wanted, like username or session id.

￼￼￼[image]

Answer (score 0):

Came across this thread as I was looking for something similar. The way I went about this is:

[Check the CM here along with the breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLaC6.png)

You can create a Pageload time/Pageview for each ECID and then further break it down by Visits. This will give you the average Page laod time for a user for a visit.

This you can cross tab with Orders. In my case visits which had orders typically